# Receiving error Failed to invoke @ExceptionHandler even with a custom @ControllerAdvice defined

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have an app with Spring 4.1.6 where I created a class for handling all exceptions as follow:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class RestControllerAdvice {
...
@ExceptionHandler({Exception.class})
public ResponseEntity<Result> handleException(final Exception ex) {
    Result res = new Result();
    try {
        Exception root = (Exception) ExceptionUtils.getRootCause(ex);
        if (root == null) {
            root = ex;
        }
        if (root instanceof BindException) {
            handleBindException(root, res);
        } else if (root instanceof ConstraintViolationException) {
            handleConstraintViolations(root, res);
        } else if (root instanceof NoHandlerFoundException) {
            handleNoHandlerFoundException(root, res);
        } else {
            logError(res, ex);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logError(res, e);
    } finally {
        if (!res.hasErrors()) {
            handleUnexpected(res);
        }
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<Result>(res, OK);
}
}
```

I realised that even though I can capture the exceptions, along with the exception in question I receive an additional error message saying the following:

```
ERROR o.s.w.s.m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - Failed to invoke @ExceptionHandler method: 
  public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.foo.Result> 
   com.foo.RestControllerAdvice.handleException(java.lang.Exception)
```

Even though this is not impeditive at any level, I'd like to understand why this is happening. Can someone please explain this to me?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

Full LOG

```
    18:11:43.690 [qtp1614440090-27] ERROR o.s.w.s.m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - Failed to invoke @ExceptionHandler method: public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.foo.Result> com.foo.RestControllerAdvice.handleException(java.lang.Exception)
org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException: null
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint.flush(ChannelEndPoint.java:192) ~[na:na]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher.flush(WriteFlusher.java:441) ~[na:na]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher.write(WriteFlusher.java:337) ~[na:na]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractEndPoint.write(AbstractEndPoint.java:128) ~[na:na]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$SendCallback.process(HttpConnection.java:646) ~[na:na]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.IteratingCallback.processing(IteratingCallback.java:246) ~[na:na]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.IteratingCallback.iterate(IteratingCallback.java:208) ~[na:na]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.send(HttpConnection.java:457) [jetty-server-9.2.4.v20141103.jar:9.2.4.v20141103]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.sendResponse(HttpChannel.java:767) [jetty-server-9.2.4.v20141103.jar:9.2.4.v20141103]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.write(HttpChannel.java:800) [jetty-server-9.2.4.v20141103.jar:9.2.4.v20141103]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:139) ~[na:na]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:132) ~[na:na]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.flush(HttpOutput.java:234) ~[na:na]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator.flush(UTF8JsonGenerator.java:1037) ~[jackson-core-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValue(ObjectMapper.java:1889) ~[jackson-databind-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
        at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:231) ~[spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:208) ~[spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:161) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(HttpEntityMethodProcessor.java:146) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:71) ~[spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:126) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.doResolveHandlerMethodException(ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.java:362) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodExceptionResolver.doResolveException(AbstractHandlerMethodExceptionResolver.java:60) [spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.resolveException(AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.java:138) [spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerExceptionResolverComposite.resolveException(HandlerExceptionResolverComposite.java:74) [spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processHandlerException(DispatcherServlet.java:1183) [spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1020) [spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:971) [spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893) [spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966) [spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857) [spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687) [servlet-api-3.1.jar:3.1.0]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842) [spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [servlet-api-3.1.jar:3.1.0]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:800) [jetty-servlet-9.2.4.v20141103.jar:9.2.4.v20141103]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669) [jetty-servlet-9.2.4.v20141103.jar:9.2.4.v20141103]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118) [spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84) [spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113) [spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113) [spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154) [spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
        at com.foo.TokenAuthFilter.doFilter(TokenAuthFilter.java:66) [classes/:na]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50) [spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87) [spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192) [spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160) [spring-security-web-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) [jetty-servlet-9.2.4.v20141103.jar:9.2.4.v20141103]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) [jetty-servlet-9.2.4.v20141103.jar:9.2.4.v20141103]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) [jetty-servlet-9.2.4.v20141103.jar:9.2.4.v20141103]
        at com.foo.config.SimpleCORSFilter.doFilter(SimpleCORSFilter.java:22) [classes/:na]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) [jetty-servlet-9.2.4.v20141103.jar:9.2.4.v20141103]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585) [jetty-servlet-9.2.4.v20141103.jar:9.2.4.v20141103]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143) [jetty-server-9.2.4.v20141103.jar:9.2.4.v20141103]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577) [jetty-security-9.2.4.v20141103.jar:9.2.4.v20141103]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223) [jetty-server-9.2.4.v20141103.jar:9.2.4.v20141103]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1125) [jetty-server-9.2.4.v20141103.jar:9.2.4.v20141103]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515) [jetty-servlet-9.2.4.v20141103.jar:9.2.4.v20141103]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185) [jetty-server-9.2.4.v20141103.jar:9.2.4.v20141103]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1059) [jetty-server-9.2.4.v20141103.jar:9.2.4.v20141103]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141) [jetty-server-9.2.4.v20141103.jar:9.2.4.v20141103]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215) [jetty-server-9.2.4.v20141103.jar:9.2.4.v20141103]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:110) [jetty-server-9.2.4.v20141103.jar:9.2.4.v20141103]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97) [jetty-server-9.2.4.v20141103.jar:9.2.4.v20141103]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:497) [jetty-server-9.2.4.v20141103.jar:9.2.4.v20141103]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310) [jetty-server-9.2.4.v20141103.jar:9.2.4.v20141103]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:248) [jetty-server-9.2.4.v20141103.jar:9.2.4.v20141103]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540) [jetty-io-9.2.4.v20141103.jar:9.2.4.v20141103]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:620) [jetty-util-9.2.4.v20141103.jar:9.2.4.v20141103]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:540) [jetty-util-9.2.4.v20141103.jar:9.2.4.v20141103]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_71]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
        at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.writev0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_71]
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.writev(SocketDispatcher.java:51) ~[na:1.7.0_71]
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:148) ~[na:1.7.0_71]
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:524) ~[na:1.7.0_71]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint.flush(ChannelEndPoint.java:172) ~[na:na]
        ... 84 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Please enable DEBUG level logging and post everything that gets logged concerning that failure: stacktrace, other messages, nested exceptions, etc.

Comment: Here it [is](http://pastebin.com/ADwrHUPZ). I am trying to get rid of this annoying "Broken Pipe" message, so I am trying to understand the previous error so I can consume the beforementioned exception.

Comment: No, I meant take the text in the pastebin and copy it here. We don't like to follow uncessary links.

Comment: Make sure, you are registering "RestControllerAdvice" in your spring configuration file.

Comment: Doesn't the annotation "register itself" because it is within the folders Spring is scanning for? From the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-controller-advice): `@ControllerAdvice annotation is a component annotation allowing implementation classes to be auto-detected through classpath scanning`

Comment: Yes, are you scanning the folder in which "RestControllerAdvice" is present?

Answer (score 20):

`IOException: Broken pipe` indicates that the client closed the connection. You caught the exception successfully, but you are trying to return a response to the client in the last line. I've managed to handle it properly with following exception handler:

```
@ExceptionHandler(IOException.class)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE)
public Object exceptionHandler(IOException e) {
    if (StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(ExceptionUtils.getRootCauseMessage(e), "Broken pipe")) { 
      return null;        //socket is closed, cannot return any response    
    } else {
      return new HttpEntity<>(e.getMessage()); 
    }
}
```

Further explanation is [here](http://mtyurt.net/2016/04/18/spring-how-to-handle-ioexception-broken-pipe/).

Comment: Nice answer. In my case, a simple `e instanceof org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException` was enough.

Answer (score 3):

You may catch the specific exception right away.

> org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException

```
@ExceptionHandler(ClientAbortException.class)
public void handleClientAbortException(ClientAbortException e) {
    log.warn(e.getMessage();
}
```